# How to use the gps to cast a notification when a user come back

Tags: java, android, gps, notifications

I want to create a reminder system for my android user.
When the user set the reminder and leave a point, I would like my service to cast him a notification when he come back near this point (let's say more than 5 minutes later).

I can create a service which keep on listening gps updates and cast a notification when the distance with the marked point is smaller than 100 meters but I am affraid it would empty the battery very fast. Furthermore, I can not really rely on Network Localization accuracy.

Is there a better way to do that ? I have heard that foursquare have just implemented a such system but I do not know if it works

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [proximity alert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) using addProximityAlert()

> Sets a proximity alert for the location given by the position
>   (latitude, longitude) and the given radius. When the device detects
>   that it has entered or exited the area surrounding the location, the
>   given PendingIntent will be used to create an Intent to be fired.

As for the battery drain :

> In case the screen goes to sleep, checks for proximity alerts happen
>   only once every 4 minutes. This conserves battery life by ensuring
>   that the device isn't perpetually awake.